# codemirror - ondblclick only affecting last element with class

Tags: javascript, dom-events

### http://jsfiddle.net/tZVsS/72/

if you double-click either of the first two elements with the class `.code` you'll notice that the setOptions will only be applied to the last element with the class `.code`. what i need to happen is when you double-click on each individual elements the setoption to be applied to that element, why is this not working and what can be done to fix it

```
(function () {
    var codes = document.getElementsByClassName("code");
    for (i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {

        var $this = codes[i];
        var $unescaped = $this.innerHTML.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");

        var isspan = $this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span";

        $this.innerHTML = "";

        if (isspan) {
            $this.style.display = "inline-block"
        } else {
            $this.style.display = "inline"
        }

        var editor = new CodeMirror($this, {
            value: $unescaped,
            mode: 'javascript',
            lineNumbers: false,
            readOnly: true
        });
        $this.ondblclick = function () {
            editor.setOption("readOnly", false);
            editor.setOption("lineNumbers", true);
        }
    }
})();
```

The HTML is below, NOTE: it's not much use, instead retrace what I've done on the fiddle for a good understanding.

```
Some code <span class="code inline">function inline() { alert('inline code') }</span> inside
a sentence.
<div class="code">function test() { return false; }</div>
```

Comment: Using $ in variable name and not using jQuery? You are really trying to confuse people looking at your code.

Comment: i see what your saying however doesn't make it invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a scope issue

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tZVsS/73/

```
(function () {
    var codes = document.getElementsByClassName("code");
    for (i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        (function ($this) { 
            var $unescaped = $this.innerHTML.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");

            var isspan = $this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span";

            $this.innerHTML = "";

            if (isspan) {
                $this.style.display = "inline-block"
            } else {
                $this.style.display = "inline"
            }

            var editor = new CodeMirror($this, {
                value: $unescaped,
                mode: 'javascript',
                lineNumbers: false,
                readOnly: true
            });
            $this.ondblclick = function () {
                console.log($this);
                editor.setOption("readOnly", false);
                editor.setOption("lineNumbers", true);
            }
        })(codes[i]);
    }
})();
```